# Magento install missing magentotheme button from admin panel

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, admin-panel

I am very new to Magento and have recently taken over a website running Magento version 1.9.2.3.

In the admin panel, it seems to be missing the "magentotheme" button which I have seen in several instructional videos.

I was wondering is this a version issue? or like a missing plugin? if so how can I fix?

Thanks in advance.

Here is an illustration of the button I am missing.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This button was added by a third-party plugin and should not exists in default magento setup.

Answer (score 0):

some third-party themes could include several options available for that theme, so they add this "shortcut" menu, where you can set up different options for the theme.

By default there is no button, and all the default options available are in:

**System > Configuration**